# Python: While printing the result of merge sort function, print option gives all steps. How to print only final sorted array?

Tags: python

Here is the code for the function which must return new sorted list, how do I get only the final arr printed, since it prints all steps?

```
def mergeSort(list_to_sort, ascend=True):
    arr=list_to_sort

    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:mid]
        right = arr[mid:]

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
        i = 0
        j = 0

        # Iterator for the main list
        k = 0

        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                # The value from the left half has been used
                arr[k] = left[i]
                # Move the iterator forward
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            # Move to the next slot
            k += 1

        # For all the remaining values
        while i < len(left):
            arr[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            arr[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

        if ascend:
            pass
        else:
            arr = arr[::-1]

    print(arr)

mergeSort([54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20],False)
```

Comment: I tried to correct the formatting but to include the first couple of lines of the code and the last line but stack overflow blocked it because of the code to comment ratio.

Comment: @LhasaDad I'm having an ongoing edit request to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you do not print within the sort function.

A sort function should just sort and do nothing else. This is always good practice, but in particular important for recursive functions.
If you want to print, sort the data and print it outside of the sort function.

I general it is recommended to separate data processing and data output / data presentation. This allows you to never change the sort function, but to print the result in one or another format or to write the result to a file, ....

Just replace the print line with

```
return arr
```

Also it seems, that your function shall not modify the input array.
Thus I suggest following changes:
change
`arr=list_to_sort` at the beginning to `arr=list_to_sort[:]` This will create a copy, so modifications to `arr` will not modify the input list.

However if you do this you also have to change:

```
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:mid]
        right = arr[mid:]

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)
```

to something like

```
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        # Recursive call on each half
        left = mergeSort(arr[:mid])
        right = mergeSort(arr[mid:])
```

You have to do this as your sort function is not sorting in place, but returning the sorted result.

and change the code calling your function to

```
tosort = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
print("tosort before sorting =", tosort)
sorted_data = mergeSort(tosort, False)
print("tosort after sorting =", tosort)
print("sorted_data =", sorted_data)
This allows you to verify, that your input data is not modified, but your output data is.
```

These commands will create following output:

```
tosort before sorting = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
tosort after sorting = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
sorted_data = [93, 77, 55, 54, 44, 31, 26, 20, 17]
```

You see, that the input data is no more modified, but the result is sorted.

Also two tips which might come in handy when dealing with lists and having to decide whether you want to copy a list or do in place modifications.

The line

```
array2 = array1
```

does NOT make a copy you just have two different names for the same array. if you change `array1` you will change `array2`

To make a (shallow) copy use

```
array2 = array1[:]
```

Following line creates a new object, which has the same name than an old object, the old object is not modified.

```
array1 = array1[:10]
```

To change array1 in place do

```
array1[:] = array1[:10]
```

Comment: Unfortunately part of the requirements is for the function itself to return a sorted list

Comment: Oh I see in fact returning a sorted list does very probably **not** mean you should print it.
It means, that you should **return** it. I will adapt my answer.

Comment: please comment also whether your mergeSort function is allowed to change the incoming data or whether it should keep the incoming data untouched and just return a sorted version.

So shall it behave like `sorted` of python or like `list.sort()`
One sorts in place, the other one creates a sorted copy and leaves the original intact. Please specify and I can adapt your code accordingly (or tell you which lines to change)

Your current solution would also sort the input array.

Comment: the function must return a *new sorted list*, to make it easier to understand, Ill post the assignment: Algorithm Implementation:
Write methods for the above algorithms called <algo name>(list_to_sort, ascend=True)
- ‘algo name’ can take on the names that appear above in bold.
- The ‘ascend’ parameter denotes whether the sorting order is ascending or descending.
- The methods returns a new sorted list (failure to do so may distort results). For
example, bubble([4, 3, 7, 1],False) will return [7,4,3,1] using the bubble sort algorithm.
- Include all 3 method in the same ex1.py file

Comment: OK, so probably the input data shall not be modified.
The fastest way to do so is to replace the line `arr=list_to_sort` with `arr=list_to_sort[:]`

change the recursive calls in your function. Will adapt my answer

Comment: answer is adapted

Comment: Im trying everything, however being new to python it takes me a while, thank you for your comments and patience, unfortunately so far, nothing worked for me, still get all process printed, but will keep trying

Comment: DId you try my changes I suggest in my current answer?

It works for me. Please read my answer line by line.

If it doesn't work, tell me and I'll just post the entire modified version of the code.
Perhaps I forgot something or you didn't apply one change.